# microsoft teamfoundation GAC assembly, same version/key but different content

Tags: tfs, assemblies, gac

I ran into a situation where two machines both had "microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.dll" in the GAC with the same version and public key.  They differed in the content they contained though.  The newer one had additional classes (e.g. BuildCoverage).  Why would the content of the dll change while the version and public key stay the same?  Is this common practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's common practice, but there are times when the AssemblyVersion (for Strong naming) isn't incremented during an "in-place" minor update to a GAC'd assembly to hot-fix a bug.  Check the actual File Version by navigating to the file via command prompt and then checking it's properties.  See if there's a difference between the files there.  That should indicate if the actual build number is different between them.  I bet a small VS hotfix has been applied to one and not another.

Comment: It is unfortunate if this is the reality.  BTW, the two assemblies differed in the classes they contain.  Not sure how that would be considered a "small" fix by any standard.   Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

It's very normal to update an AssemblyFileVersion but not update the AssemblyVersion attribute.  This is how hotfixes for .NET get shipped for example.   The key is to test the hell out of the assembly to make sure it's completly backwards compatible to prevent DLL hell.